# New Laptop stopped booting after a good week

Tags: boot, 13.10, i3-wm

So far I always could solve my problems by reading through questions already asked but this time I can't find any prescedental case, so here we go:

I got a new laptop for christmas, immediately installed Ubuntu 13.10 and changed the windowmanager to i3. No dual boot, nothing fancy, just Ubuntu and i3. Today it suddenly stopped booting after working just fine for about a week. It gets to the Ubuntu-loading screen and the loading-animation works, but I waited for severeal minutes and nothing happens.

I checked the boot-options, they are fine. Aside from that I know neither what to test nor what could be the problem. Any ideas?

**Edit**: I totally forgot the option to try booting into recovery mode. Didn't solve the problem, but now I know, that the last thing it tries to do is

```
resume: libgcrypt version 1.5.0
```

That's where the screen freezes for about two or three minutes. Then it says:

```
resume: Could not stat hte resume device file '/dev/dm-0'
        Please type in the full path name to try again or press ENTER to boot the system:
```

It reacts to nothing after that.

Comment: post the final edit as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did some further searches and found the solution. Apparently **uswsusp** sometimes causes this problem when **/home is encrypted**. The solution was to boot into a live-system, mount /home as root and uninstall uswsusp. A step-by-step solution can be found [here](http://dtbaker.net/uncategorized/ubuntu-13-04-hibernate-issue-could-not-stat-the-resume-device-file-devdm-0/):

> After installing a fresh Ubuntu 13.04 I noticed the laptop would no
>   longer hibernate when the lid was closed.
>
> I installed the hibernate package (`apt-get install hibernate`) and
>   then ran `sudo hibernate`
>
> This resulted in a laptop that would not boot. initramfs issue that
>   could not be circumvented through recovery mode:
>
> ```
> resume: libcrypt version: 
> resume: could not stat the resume device file /dev/dm-0
> Please type in the full path name to try again or press ENTER to boot the system:
> ```
>
> Pressing enter does nothing, the only keystroke that works is
>   ctrl+alt+del
>
> So after some googling this is what I tried:
>
> 1. Boot into ubuntu live cd/usb – the same one I used to install ubuntu earlier today
> 2. Mount my system and chroot into it:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir /mnt/temp/
>    mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/temp/
>    cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/temp/etc/resolv.conf
>    chroot /mnt/temp/
>    mount /proc
>    #optional commands: not sure what caused the issue
>    apt-get purge uswsusp
>    apt-get purge hibernate
>    dpkg-reconfigure initramfs-tools
>    ```
> 3. Reboot the live cd and see if that works.

If needed, replace `/dev/sda1` with the partition with Ubuntu's root filesystem inside it.

Comment: Note you can accept your own answer using the tick next to it :D it also helps to embed information here in case the link goes dead

Comment: And *please* don't put "solved" in the title, but click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)